# Laravel Creating Reactivate Button Error

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I want to create a reactivate account option so that after users deactivate their account, they can always click reactivate and go back.

Now the problem is when I click on the link which should call the controller function, it is not working and keep returning to the `/auth` page no matter what I do.

Now here is my Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('/');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if (!$user->activated) {
            $activation = action('Auth\AuthController@getActivationMail', ['username' => $user->username]);
            Auth::logout();

            return redirect()->guest('auth')
                ->withErrors(array('message' => 'Please activate your account. Re-send your activation by clicking <a href=' . $activation . '>here</a>.'));
        }



         // the main code starts here

        else if (!$user->enabled) {
            $reactivation = action('UserController@postActivateUser');
            Auth::logout();
            //$reactivation = $user->enabled = 1;
            //$user->save();
            return redirect('/auth')->withErrors(array('message' => 'Your account has been deactivated. You can reactivate your account by clicking <a href='. $reactivation .'> Here </a>.'))->withInput();
        }

        $user->runDailyNotifications();
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

}

I created postActivate function in the UserController since there is a similar function (the similar function here):

```
    public function postDeactivateUser(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {            
        $user = Auth::user();
        User::removeData($user);
        $user->enabled = false;
        $user->save();

        return response()->json(['result' => true, 'msg' => 'Your account has been deactivated.']);
    }
}
```

So that I created a similar one:

```
public function postActivateUser(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->enabled = 1;
    $user->save();

    return response()->json(['result' => true, 'msg' => 'Your account has been activated.']);
}
```

and a route:

```
Route::get('auth/activate', 'UserController@postActivateUser');
```

I'm not sure what can I do to make it right, thanks for anyone helping me.

Answer (score 0):

What Laravel version are you running?
Your middleware requires that the user has to be logged in in order to activate his account, otherwise it redirects to auth screen.

```
if (!Auth::check()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('/');
        }
    }
```

You should exclude your activation route from the middleware and use the activation token in order to identify the unauthenticated user and reactivate his account.

Put this line outside the auth middleware in your routes file.

```
Route::get('auth/activate', 'UserController@postActivateUser');
```

And then work in the postActivateUser method, you should change the request->token parameter name according to your activation url and the User::findByToken acording to your database field.

```
public function postActivateUser(Request $request)
{
    // get the user from activation token

    $user = User::findByToken($request->token);
    $user->enabled = 1;
    $user->save();

    return response()->json(['result' => true, 'msg' => 'Your account has been activated.']);
}
```

Comment: Hi! I have put the route into the route.php file and changed the UserController into the function you mentioned, however it is still not working (same problem as before, no error messages)

Comment: If you have the 'auth' middleware in your Kernel.php this will not work.

Comment: Unfortunately, It is inside Kernel.php, now I'm not sure what to do

Comment: You can try this [tutorial](https://tuts.codingo.me/user-activation-with-middleware), but it is for L 5.3